# Disable warning "Access can be package-private" for @Transactional methods

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have several public methods annotated with `@Transactional` and IntelliJ shows the warning that they can be package-private or private.

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething() {
  ///body
}
```

Since methods annotated with `@Transactional` should be public, how can I disable in IntelliJ this inspection/warning **only for those methods**?

Comment: If you're using Spring in proxy mode (the default), `@Transactional` only works for methods accessed through an interface, and since method implementing an interface must be `public`, that will prevents the warning.

Answer (score 13):

Sadly, it isn't possible to make all methods annotated with `@Transactional` clear the warning, although it is possible to add `@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")` to make the warning go away.
Alternatively, you can disable this inspection altogether in IntelliJ IDEA by going to `File`→`Settings`→`Editor`→`Inspections`.
In the list show in this view you will want to navigate through the subcategories: `Java`→`Declaration redundancy` and uncheck the checkbox called "Declaration access can be weaker" that will be available then. If you wish to disable this for future projects, choose the profile "Default" from the dropdown menu labelled "Profile", otherwise, just do this for "Project Default".